# template non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, non-type-template-parameter

Following is my code to register a free function or member function as callback.

Find code here https://cppinsights.io/s/58dcf235

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class IEvent
{
    
public:
    int m_EventType;
    virtual ~IEvent() {}
};

template<class...Args>
class Event : public IEvent {};

template<int eventType,class...Args>
class Event<int eventType, bool(Args...)> : public IEvent
{
public:
    Event(bool(*func)(Args...)) :m_FnPtr(func)
    { 
         m_EventType = eventType;
         m_ListenersList.push_back(m_FnPtr);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Event(T* obj, bool(T::* Func)(Args...))
    {
        m_EventType = eventType;
        m_FnPtr = [obj, Func](Args&&... args)->bool {
            return (obj->*Func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
        
        m_ListenersList.push_back(m_FnPtr);
    }

    void NotifyListeners(Args&&...args) const
    {
        for (auto& itr : m_ListenersList)
        {
            (itr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        
    }
private:
    std::function<bool(Args...)> m_FnPtr;
    std::vector<std::function<bool(Args...)>> m_ListenersList; 
};

class Window
{
public:
    bool OnKeyUp(bool, double)
    {
        cout << endl << "Member Function called";
        return true;
    }

    bool OnClicked()
    {
        cout << endl << "OnClicked";
        return true;
    }
    
    //using KeyupListenerType = Event<"KeyUp", bool(bool, double)>;
};

int main()
{
    Window w;
    Event<90,bool(bool, double)> evnt(&w, &Window::OnKeyUp);
    //Event<100,bool()> evnt(&w, &Window::OnClicked);
    evnt.NotifyListeners(true, 6.8);
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting errors at line:

```
Event<90,bool(bool, double)> evnt(&w, &Window::OnKeyUp);
```

I'm trying to assign an event type to the event listener as shown below.
I want to assign the event type during instantiation itself. But I get the following errors

```
26 | class Event<int, bool(Args...)> : public IEvent
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:7: note:         ‘eventType’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:80:32: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template class Event’
   80 |     Event<90,bool(bool, double)> evnt(&w, &Window::OnKeyUp);
      |                                ^
main.cpp:80:32: note:   expected a type, got ‘90’
main.cpp:80:62: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
   80 |     Event<90,bool(bool, double)> evnt(&w, &Window::OnKeyUp);
      |                                                              ^
main.cpp:80:62: error: cannot convert ‘bool (Window::*)(bool, double)’ to ‘int’ in initialization
main.cpp:81:10: error: request for member ‘NotifyListeners’ in ‘evnt’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   81 |     evnt.NotifyListeners(true, 6.8);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What mistake I'm doing? How to pass non-type parameters?

Comment: The `bool(bool, double)` you're giving it is a type.

Comment: yes. It tells what type of function pointer to take. If I remove the 'int' parameter, it works fine. but i want to assign event type during instantiation itself, so that later i can use using attribute like: using KeyupListenerType = Event<Window::KeyUpEnum, bool(bool, double)>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base declaration does not match your specialization.

The base implementation has `template <class...Args>` while the specialzation wants `template <int eventType, class...Args>`.

You also put an extra `int` that does not belong there in the declaration for the specialization here:

```
template<int eventType,class...Args>
class Event<int eventType, bool(Args...)> : public IEvent
            ^^^ here
```

The adjusted code would look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class IEvent
{
    
public:
    int m_EventType;
    virtual ~IEvent() {}
};

template<int eventType, class...Args>
class Event : public IEvent {};

template<int eventType,class...Args>
class Event<eventType, bool(Args...)> : public IEvent
{
public:
    Event(bool(*func)(Args...)) :m_FnPtr(func)
    { 
         m_EventType = eventType;
         m_ListenersList.push_back(m_FnPtr);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Event(T* obj, bool(T::* Func)(Args...))
    {
        m_EventType = eventType;
        m_FnPtr = [obj, Func](Args&&... args)->bool {
            return (obj->*Func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
        
        m_ListenersList.push_back(m_FnPtr);
    }

    void NotifyListeners(Args&&...args) const
    {
        for (auto& itr : m_ListenersList)
        {
            (itr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        
    }
private:
    std::function<bool(Args...)> m_FnPtr;
    std::vector<std::function<bool(Args...)>> m_ListenersList; 
};

class Window
{
public:
    bool OnKeyUp(bool, double)
    {
        cout << endl << "Member Function called";
        return true;
    }

    bool OnClicked()
    {
        cout << endl << "OnClicked";
        return true;
    }
    
    //using KeyupListenerType = Event<"KeyUp", bool(bool, double)>;
};

int main()
{
    Window w;
    Event<90,bool(bool, double)> evnt(&w, &Window::OnKeyUp);
    //Event<100,bool()> evnt(&w, &Window::OnClicked);
    evnt.NotifyListeners(true, 6.8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to define the non-specialized version, and use a single arg. since you're passing a function type, so `template <int eventType, class Fn> class Event;`.

Comment: yes..I'll correct it. Thank you